# Autoloader not finding classes from my plugin

Tags: oop, namespace, autoloading

I am trying to work with autoloader in my plugin.

In the main file of my plugin I have

```
use My_Plugin\Includes;

require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-autoloader.php' );

$autoloader = new Includes\Autoloader();
```

And in my `includes/class-autoloader.php` file I have

```
namespace My_Plugin\Includes;

class Autoloader() {
    public __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register( [ $this, 'autoloader' ] );
    }

    public autoloader( $class_name ) {
        error_log( print_r( $class_name, true ) );

        if ( strpos( $class_name, 'My_Plugin' ) === false ) {
          return;
        }
    }
}
```

But none of the classes that I have in my plugin will be shown in my `error_log.txt`. I see classes from WooCommerce which I have activated on my test site.

Why am I not seeing my classes in the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Given the first PHP code snippet you posted, I don't see that you're using the class yet, which explains why you're not seeing your classes in the autoload error log that you're debugging with.

Note that `use` will not trigger PHP's autoloader.

```
use My_Plugin\Includes;
```

You need to actually instantiate a class, check that it exists, or do something else that requires the class to actually be loaded into memory at runtime. Only then will the autoload queue receive a request to load one of your class files.

As it stands, the only class you're using is the Autoloader class itself, which doesn't need to be autoloaded, because you've included the class file explicitly.

Comment: Hmmm, so how to avoid this issue? Should I just call the `spl_autoload_register()` out of the class? Without any instantiation?

Comment: The point of autoloading is to NOT load classes until they are actually used for the first time. The goal of autoload is to minimize used resources by loading classes when they are needed only.

Comment: @MilanPetrovic I know the _concept_ of autoloading, I just never used it before, so I'm not sure how should I do it. I found some tutorials, but so far nothing worked...

Comment: @dingo_d What you have is fine already. Just complete the work that you need to do in the autoload handler that you've registered. That way your class files will be loaded whenever you _do_ use them. All that's left then, is just to use one of your classes. So create a test class named `My_Plugin\Test`, and run something like `class_exists('My_Plugin\\Test')` to trigger the autoloader for that class.

Comment: Note the second `$autoload` argument to `class_exists`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: @jaswrks I'm following this tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-wordpress-plugins-4--cms-27342 And I should see class names because I have namespaces set up in my plugin. I also have `requires` in the plugin because it was written and working before, but I wanted to add namespacing to it...

Comment: Having namespaces in a plugin class doesn't equate to autoloading. Namespacing is a good practice, but unrelated to autoloading. The tutorial you're following is a good one, and has connected the two together, but they are in fact unrelated; i.e., you can autoload without namespaces, and you can have namespaces without autoloading.

Comment: Having `requires` in the plugin, also does not equate to autoloading. The only way to trigger an autoload request is to attempt to use a class in PHP that doesn't exist yet (i.e., has not been require'd yet). Only then will PHP attempt to load the class file automatically, and it's at this point that your autoload handler will be called upon. So you should `require` from inside the autoload handler that you've registered. Another tutorial that may help you: https://resoundingechoes.net/development/autoloading-classes-php/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'll see the link that you pasted.